# Sources for an Android Image gallery view with pinch zoom, touch swipe etc

Tags: java, android, eclipse, touch

Are there any open sources for a View similiar to Android system gallery? I mean a view that can swipe pictures with gestures, zoom it by double tap, zoom by two-finger gestures etc?
Maybe some non-free but recommended libraries?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Cyanogen Mod has the Entire Camera Application (contains the gallery) here:

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Gallery

That version may be modified some. If you dig thru the source tree on grepcode, or git yourself a copy of it and dig thru it locally you should be able to find the stock camera app source code which should contain the gallery.

Comment: Thanks. I have downloaded and compiled the sources. Almost everything is ok except for the fact that the swipe effect is not implemented. The images are simply switched on swipe gesture - no animation is displayed.

Comment: my mistake, I was under the impression that they were using the stock gallery. I'm surprised they removed the animations.