# fling and pinchzoom for an imageview in one activity

Tags: android, android-gesture

I have an Imageview(like a Magazine page).When i swype in to that image then i want the next image(page).Also want Zoom in and out option  for this image.How i can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Check this article: [ImageView Zoom and Scroll](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/).

Comment: I guess you are looking for a library that does that.

Comment: See duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975586/sources-for-an-android-image-gallery-view-with-pinch-zoom-touch-swipe-etc

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672210/android-combine-swipe-and-pinch-to-zoom

Comment: check my ans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57357861/9764941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already researched separately on [pinch-to-zoom](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847) and [swipe gestures](http://www.anddev.org/gesturedetector_and_gesturedetectorongesturelistener-t3204.html), you may want to impose limitations on useability. When the image is zoomed (occupying an area greater than the screen size), you should disable swipe detection, and enable it again once the image size is less than the screen size.

Comment: how can i detect whether it is a pinch zoom or swype gesture?

Comment: in detecting pinch zoom, you're using MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN to detect the second finger touching the screen. while there's no MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, whatever the onTouchEvent is processing should be a pinch gesture. try setting up flags to enable/disable swipe detection. that of course, in support to checking for the size of the image, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: But it contradicts the scroll gesture. Isn't there a more generic way doing this? I mean one component with pinch to zoom and scroll. Another with swipe and make them work together.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented such a library. There are still minor issues but it's functional and can be extended.

Here's the fork on github: https://github.com/kilaka/ImageViewZoom

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268806/android-gallery-with-pinch-zoom) post on a a gallery (swipe between photos) with pinch-to-zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented it and it works great

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView