# Android - combine swipe and pinch-to-zoom

Tags: android, imageview, gallery, swipe, pinchzoom

- We have the [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html), which support swiping.
- We also have 3rd-party components that support pinch-to-zoom on ImageView, such as [ImageViewTouch](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom/blob/master/ImageViewTouch/src/it/sephiroth/android/library/imagezoom/ImageViewTouch.java) in [ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom).

**Now I would like to combine them both.**

The problem is that the swipe events get consumed by the [ImageViewTouch](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom/blob/master/ImageViewTouch/src/it/sephiroth/android/library/imagezoom/ImageViewTouch.java) and missed by the Gallery.

**How can consume events by both components?**

That would solve my problem, because, eventually, after a few events, each component will know how to react accordingly.
For example, if the first event is [ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN), it can be part of a pinch-to-zoom or part of a swipe. Both components (Gallery and ImageViewTouch) should consume it in order to know what to do in following events.

Comment: I found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268806/android-gallery-with-pinch-zoom. I'll investigate it...

Comment: For zoom you can Look Into [Zooming](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/04/update-pinch-to-zoom-example-and.html). Now place this inside one ViewPager

Comment: @Sameer: Thanks. What about integrating scrolling within a zoomed photo with scrolling between the different photos?

Comment: You can use HorizontalScrollView also. But in that get position of click item  is not easy. You write extra code for the same. Viewpager provide you position of current Item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I combined both components by changing some code in ImageViewZoom. The change was for the events to return a value if they were consumed by the ImageViewTouch. If so, than the event should not be passed to the gallery. If the event is not consumed by the ImageView, than the gallery should consume it (if it can).

There are still some small issues, but it's functional. Hopefully other people in the community can help.

Here's the fork on github: https://github.com/kilaka/ImageViewZoom

Thanks.