# how to add pinch to zoom textview in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pinchzoom

I searched many blogs regarding pinch to zoom `TextView` in `ViewPager`. I just found many answers for pinch to zoom `ImageView`.

How I can add pinch to zoom in ViewPager.

Here are the links, which I read before posting:

- [View Pager + ImageView +Pinch Zoom + Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943831/view-pager-imageview-pinch-zoom-rotation)
- [Android - combine swipe and pinch-to-zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672210/android-combine-swipe-and-pinch-to-zoom?rq=1)

**Updated**

```
@Override
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
    if (v instanceof TouchImageView) {
        return ((TouchImageView) v).canScrollHorizontallyFroyo(-dx);
    } else {
        return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
    }
}
```

I am getting error in `if (v instanceof TouchImageView)` . error message says ,`TouchImageView` cannot be resolved

Comment: Can you elaborate on issues you are facing  while using solutions  given in first link ?  I thought it should work

Comment: view pager not zooming text.whenever i try to pinch to zoom textview ,page will scroll  @Ramesh.

Comment: Must be a problem with event delegation . is it possible to share pseudo code

Comment: i will post the code soon.because i deleted the code which i used . thank you for the response @Ramesh

Answer (score 1):

Create a private class `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` which extends `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` in your activity like this

```
public class SimpleOnScaleGestureListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    float scaleFactor;

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        if(isTablet(getApplicationContext())){
            setFontStyleandSizeTab();
        }else{
            setFontStyleandSize();
        }
        scaleFactor = Math.max(15.0f, Math.min(scaleFactor,36.0f));
         View view=pager.getFocusedChild().findViewById(R.id.article_content)  ;
         View article_intro=pager.getFocusedChild().findViewById(R.id.article_intro)  ;

         ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
         int count=group.getChildCount();

       for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            View child=group.getChildAt(i);
              if(child instanceof TextView){
                  TextView textView=(TextView)child;
                  textView.setTextSize(scaleFactor);

              }
           }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Inside `onScale` function what we are doing is getting `ScaleFactor` first and setting limits for zooming text. Here textsize minimum is **15** and maximum will be **36**.
From next line we are appling pinch zoom for Textview inside viewpager.

```
View view=pager.getFocusedChild().findViewById(R.id.article_content);
```

In this first I am obtaining viewpager current item by calling `pager.getFocusedChild()` from that I am obtaining a linearlayout which contains all that textviews which I want to zoom.

You can pass textview ids directly there. At runtime I am adding textviews to this layout that why I follow like this.
If you want to zoom mutilple textviews at a time which have same parent then you can follow like this or you can create multiple View instance by passing textview id directly.

```
textView.setTextSize(scaleFactor);
```

Here I am applying scaling for textview

you must **override** a method to detect touch event with viewpager

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

}
```

And in `onCreate()`  create ScaleGestureDetector instance like this:

```
scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new simpleOnScaleGestureListener());
```

Now you can apply a smooth zooming in viewpager.